# Multivariate Multiple Classification

Tags: r, classification, scikit-learn, multivariate-analysis

Is it possible to have multiple (at least 3) dependent variables in a single classification model. I know this can be accomplished in a regression model but I need to perform this with a classification model.

My three DVs are correlated so I do not want to simply write three seperate classification models. Does anyone know of a way to do this in either R or python's scikit?

Comment: Neural networks would allows for such things in a pretty straightforward way.

Comment: Do you have any examples to show this? I have looked extensively and have found no such example.

Comment: In a neural network setting, I would add new output nodes for every extra DV. You can reuse the rest of the architecture (e.g. all hidden layers, which constitute the main part of learning).